# Redirecting Many Dynamic URLs (301)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is generating dynamic URLs through categories and it outputs the same information on two separate URLs (In this example it's "**buildings**" and "**houses**")

I would like to redirect all URLs that have `/buildings/` in the URL to the same one with `/houses/` instead.

**For example:**

```
/buildings/united-states/arizona/tucson/
```

to

```
/houses/united-states/arizona/tucson/
```

There are many URLs like this and I would like to use a code that does this for all.

I have tried
`RewriteRule ^buildings/(\d[^/]+) /houses/$1/ [R=301,L]`, but it didn't seem to work (it still pointed to the `/buildings/` URL.

Appreciate all your comments and guidance, thank you!

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase for the reply. I've edited the comment to reflect the outcome more accurately. It basically didn't redirect and pointed to the /buildings/ URL instead. 

Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: So, from your example, `/buildings/` always occurs at the start of the URL-path?

Comment: Thanks correct @MrWhite. The URL structure of all pages will be the same. They always occur in the same structure /buildings/ and /houses/ after the TLD.

Comment: `\d` would match a _digit_. The example URL you have given, does not contain a single digit anywhere.

Comment: Why such a complicated pattern to begin with? Just catch _anything_ that comes after `buildings/` - `^buildings/(.+)`

Comment: @CBroe because I don't know better. Thanks for pointing that it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^buildings/(\d[^/]+) /houses/$1/ [R=301,L]
> ```

For some reason have a `\d` (shorthand character class) that matches digits 0-9 only, so this won't match the example URL. Also, `[^/]+` would seem unnecessary if it can be followed by anything anyway.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^buildings/(.*) /houses/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches `/buildings/<anything>`. The `$1` backreference holds the `<anything>` part.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended. You should clear you browser cache before testing.

This needs to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, before any existing rewrites.